# Reading contents of relative file from batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, filereader

I have the following directory structure:

```
C:\Users\myuser\tmp\version\
    version.bat
    VERSION
```

My `version.bat` file:

```
set contents=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('VERSION') do set contents=%content% %%i

echo contents
```

What I am *attempting* to do is, when the user runs `version.bat` it reads the contents of the `VERSION` file into a variable called `contents`, and then echo those contents to `STDOUT`.

When I run this I see the following output:

```
C:\Users\myuser\tmp\version>set contents=

C:\Users\myuser\tmp\version>for /F "delims=" %i in ('VERSION') do set content= %i
```

And then my computer starts doing all sorts of weird things, gets slow, locks up, and takes for ever to kill the batch script. Where am I going awry?

Comment: I'm not at Windows machine right now so cannot check; but two things come to my mind - You probably want `type VERSION` (ie contents of file) ? And if I remember correctly, using parameter %i in following "do" clause supposedly used %%i. I'll look it up tomorrow, if none is able to help sooner.

Comment: If VERSION contains a single line you can just use `set /p contents="" < VERSION`.

Comment: Also, using `%%i in ('VERSION')` will execute VERSION. Instead you want to loop over the file contents using `%%i in (VERSION)`.

Answer (score 0):

Checked, working

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type version') do set "VERSION=%%x"
echo %VERSION%
```

probably other idea from comment might work too, but i haven't checked that.